# Simple Calculation of Speed Issue in C

Tags: c, algebra

I'm trying to calculate the speed/velocity based on total stopping distance and mu. It's basically using the quadratic formula to get the positive root for velocity so that the equation will work. But my answer for the example test at the bottom of the code "speed(83.959876093, 0.7)->100" doesn't match and I'm stumped to figure out what might be the issue. I broke down every part of the quadratic formula in multiple variables.

```
#include <math.h>
#define G 9.81  // this is in m/s so need to convert the final output from m/s to km/h 
double speed(double d, double mu) {
        double conv_num = 60 * 60;  // used to convert from sec to hours 
        double conv_den = 1000; // used to convert from m to km 
        double conv = 1 / conv_den;
        double km_d = conv * d;  // convert input distance in meters to km 
        // use quadratic formula to solve for v given total stopping distance (after conversion, so it's km_hr_d)
        // given ax^2 + bx + c = 0, ((-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) / (2a) ) 
        // (v^2/(2*mu*g) + v - d = 0) so b = 1, a = 1/(2*mu*g), c = -d
        double b = 1;
        double c = -km_d;
        double constant = 2 * mu * G;
        double a = 1 / constant;
        double sqrt_quad_num = (b *b) - (4 * a * c);
        double quad_num = -b + sqrt(sqrt_quad_num);
        double quad_den = 2 * a;
        double root = quad_num / quad_den;
        root = root * conv_num;
        printf("sqrt_quad_num: %f\n", sqrt_quad_num);
        printf("quad_num: %f\n", quad_num);
        printf("quad_den: %f\n", quad_den);
        printf("inter_root: %f\n", inter_root);
        printf("root is %f\n", root);
        return root;
}

// supposed to get speed(83.9598760937531, 0.7) -> 100.0

My results are: 
sqrt_quad_num: 1.024453
quad_num: 0.012153
quad_den: 0.145624
inter_root: 0.083453
root is 300.430032
```

Comment: Print all your intermediate variables. If the operations are otherwise correct, chances are you're uniintentionally performing integer operations where you think you're performing floating pointer operations.

Comment: Do you get the correct answer when doing this manually with a calculator? If not, the problem is with your formula. If yes, look for the first step in this code which doesn't match your manual results.

Comment: What are the units for d? If it's metres (as I think it should be, since g is in m/s as you say) why are you converting that to km before solving the quadratic?

Comment: Wow @rup this is embarrassing. I was trying to multiply the converted km with the G constant which was in meters. I saved the full conversion at the end and now it works. Thank you this was a very simple error to make.

Comment: Not at all, I'm sure we've all done worse. FWIW I've found a few websites that say the stopping distance formula is just d = v^2 / 2*mu*g, without the +v term (e.g. [1](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/crstp.html) [2](https://softschools.com/formulas/physics/stopping_distance_formula/89/) ). But if that matches what you were expecting then great. (Or does yours include 1 second thinking time?)

Comment: yup you're right the second v term was the reaction distance part of the total stopping distance (with a reaction time of 1 thinking second)